# Force an android phone to sleep, in order to test?

Tags: android, sleep-mode, android-powermanager

I'm writing an android application that depends on network activity and the alarm manager sometimes waking the phone up from a sleeping state.

My question is how can I reliably test this on device? Ideally, how can I force the phone into a full-on sleeping state. Failing that, how can I know for sure when the phone has fully gone to sleep?

How do you test your Alarm Manager / Wake Lock / Sleep handling code?

Answer (score 12):

Turn off the screen of the device/emulator and then run the following commands:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

Re-run the second one until you get the message "IDLE". This works on devices running Android 6.0 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

a. Put the device to "discharging" in settings (follow instructions in the red boxes).

b. Turn off the device screen by pressing the "power" button (blue box).

[image: Turn of the phone in Emulator]

**Step 2**

a. To directly put the device to sleep mode, run:

`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle`

b. Or slowly step into sleep mode, run:

`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step` multiple times.

**Step 3**

To confirm device idle status, run:

`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle get deep`

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the power button on the device should put it to sleep. There is also a [goToSleep(long time)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep(long)) method in the [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), but that requires [DEVICE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER) permission, which is reserved for system applications.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have been doing, but I suspect that pressing power puts the display to sleep immediately, but does not necessarily force the CPU to sleep (which apparently can eventually happen - judging by this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP)

Comment: Hmm, I thought power did this. In the debug log I'm used to seeing a message like "I'm tired, going to sleep" when I press the power button, so I'm pretty sure it is going to sleep / scaling back the processor.

Comment: Maybe this is a per-device thing. I'm using a Milestone, and it doesn't say that for me.. the screen just turns off, and i keep getting log messages as usual.

Comment: You need to disconnect form USB to see true sleep effects on your app.  Leaving USB plugged in through Eclipse does strange things with background services.

Comment: of course what @Ryan Conrad states is nonsense - this is what wakelock is for - if some app acquires it the device will not go asleep when power button is pressed, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/wakelocks-detect-no-sleep-issues-in-android-applications

Comment: @MarianPaździoch you realize the article you linked to was written 3 years after I posted this answer. And, how is it nonsense? Pressing the power button does put it to sleep. The question was "how do i force the phone in to a full sleep state", wakelock keeps it awake, the opposite of what the original question was.

Answer (score -4):

if u want to test on the emulator then from home screen press
menu -> setting -> applications -> development ->uncheck stay awake